# use static variable as key in JSON

Tags: json, groovy, static

I have a problem while building JSONObject

```
MyCustomerClass.groovy

class MyCustomerClass {
  static String MY_NAME = "my_name"

  public JSONObject formDetails() {
     def customer = getCustomer()
     JsonBuilder data = new JsonBuilder()
    data {
    customer {MY_NAME customer.name}
    // more object details
    }
     JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data.toPrettyString())
     return json
  }
}
```

When it is building the json object it is not replacing `MY_NAME` as `my_name`. Instead it takes `"MY_NAME"` itself the key. 
Am i missing something??. But if i use static variable as value it is replacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `"$MY_NAME"` to get the content of the static variable. Like

`customer {"$MY_NAME" customer.name}`